# How to run Scala compiled code in command line?

Tags: scala

I have the following `hello.scala` file:

```
object hello {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

After using `scalac` to compile it, I get back `hello.class` and `hello$.class`.

How to execute it using `java` command? What should I put where `???` are?

```
$ java ??? hello
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for

```
java -cp /wherever/my/scala/lives/lib/scala-library.jar hello
```

or you can just

```
scala hello
```

Comment: You'll also need to add the current directory to the classpath, so that should be `java -cp .:/wherever/scala-library.jar hello` - the current dir is only used by default if classpath is not specified.

Comment: Where can I get the scala-library.jar??

Comment: @user3416134 - It's in the lib directory of any Scala distribution from http://scala-lang.org and ought to be in the same directory in every Linux Scala package.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `scala` command to run it. i.e. `scala hello`

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be the time to introduce the user yet another tool that would ease developing Scala applications - compiling the sources, building a single-jar artifact with all the dependencies and such. I don't think the single `object hello` application is the last word on what the OP develop in Scala and ultimately the tool's required.

With that said, I'd strongly suggest a project build tool and sbt might be a good fit.

Download the sbt launcher from [the sbt project's web site](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html) and run `sbt` in the directory where the `hello` object sits in.

To run the `hello` object, execute `sbt` and let it execute other commands - of which `run` is the command to run the `hello` object application.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/hello-object
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to hello-object (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/)
[hello-object]> run
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/}hello-object...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Running hello
Hello World!
[success] Total time: 12 s, completed Mar 16, 2014 2:32:39 PM
```

If you however need to know what exactly the command line was to `run` your `hello` object, execute `last` or `last run` to be explicit and have the parts been printed out for you.

```
[hello-object]> last
[debug]
[debug] Initial source changes:
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] External API changes: API Changes: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug]
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings:
[debug]
[info] Running hello
[debug] Waiting for threads to exit or System.exit to be called.
[debug]   Classpath:
[debug]     /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/classes
[debug]     /Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar
[debug] Waiting for thread run-main-3 to terminate.
[debug]     Thread run-main-3 exited.
[debug] Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
[debug] Sandboxed run complete..
[debug] Exited with code 0
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 16, 2014 2:41:57 PM
[debug] > shell
```

The `Classpath` part after `Running hello` is what you need - the classpath to run your `hello` object.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/hello-object
$ java -cp /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/classes:/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar hello
Hello World!
```

Once you're satisfied with the result of your Scala development and the application appears ready for production deployment, execute `package` to create a jar file for other projects to use it (even Java ones).

```
[hello-object]> package
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/hello-object_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 16, 2014 2:34:34 PM
```

You may want to publish it to Ivy2 (default) or Maven repositories with `publishLocal` so the other Scala/Java/JRuby/Groovy projects could use it.

```
[hello-object]> publishLocal
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/hello-object_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/hello-object_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] :: delivering :: default#hello-object_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT :: 0.1-SNAPSHOT :: integration :: Sun Mar 16 14:35:57 CET 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/api...
model contains 2 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/hello-object/target/scala-2.10/hello-object_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published hello-object_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/hello-object_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/hello-object_2.10.pom
[info]  published hello-object_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/hello-object_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/hello-object_2.10.jar
[info]  published hello-object_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/hello-object_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/srcs/hello-object_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published hello-object_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/hello-object_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/docs/hello-object_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/hello-object_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Mar 16, 2014 2:36:01 PM
```

And the last but not least - to have a single jar with all the dependencies bundled use the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach, call the file for instance`hello.sh`, set it to executable,

```
chmod +x hello.sh
```

Note the header of the file,

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -savecompiled "$0" "$@"
!#

object hello {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

Run it simply with

```
./hello.sh
```

The switch `-savecompiled` creates a JAR file on the first execution, following executions startup will be faster since no (re)compilation of the scripted code is required.